# WoW Weakaruas Tracking Multiple Enemy Units

Tags: lua, lua-table, world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft I've been working on a Weakaura for a little while now that will track how many enemy units are alive that the player has damaged. One of the major issues this runs into is that while in a group `COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED` forces the aura to fire any time someone in your group performs an action, which can cause a lot of dropped frames. The only other option that I've been able to come across is `COMBAT_LOG_EVENT`, however this wont trigger when an enemy has died and so it wouldn't be removed from the list.

My Questions: is there any way to gather this data on a thread other than the UI thread to prevent dropped frames? While gathering this data on another thread will the data be able to be used to display information to the user?

Below are the currently used triggers (these all work as expected)

Trigger 1

Type - Custom

Event Type - Event

Event(s) - COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED

Custom Trigger:

```
function(...)
    ADDS = ADDS or {}; -- Where enemy units are stored

    local _, _, event, _, src, _, _, _, dest, _, _, _ = select(1, ...);
    local player = UnitGUID("player");

    -- Attempts to only read data coming from the player casting harmful abilities
    if ((event == "SPELL_DAMAGE") and (src == player)) then

        -- Checks if the enemy unit is already being tracked and that it is NOT
        -- a part of your group (prevents friendly fire events from adding a friendly
        -- unit to this list)
        if ((not tContains(ADDS, dest)) and (not tContains(GROUP, dest))) then
            table.insert(ADDS, dest);
        end
    elseif event=="UNIT_DIED" then -- Remove a unit if it has died
        for i = #ADDS, 1, -1 do
            if ADDS[i] == dest then
                table.remove(ADDS, i);
            end
        end
    end

    return true;
end
```

The above block of code is the cause of the frames being dropped. The next trigger is merely a means to reset the list when combat starts or ends (pretty certain that nothing in this block is causing dropped frames but wanted to include it just in case).

Trigger 2

Type - Custom

Event Type - Event

Event(s) - PLAYER_REGEN_DISABLED, PLAYER_REGEN_ENABLED

```
function(...)
    GROUP = GROUP or {};

    local size = GetNumGroupMembers();

    if (size == 0) then
        GROUP = {};
    end

    if (size ~= #GROUP and size ~= 0) then
        for i = 1, size do
            local name = GetRaidRosterInfo(i);

            if (name ~= nil) then
                local guid = UnitGUID(name);

                if (not tContains(GROUP, guid)) then
                    table.insert(GROUP, guid);
                end
            end
        end
    end

    ADDS = {};
    return true;
end
```